# Extra space in \today command with polyglossia

Tags: spacing, babel, polyglossia, date

Compiling with `polyglossia`, there's extra space before the year in the `\today` command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
    \setdefaultlanguage{norsk}

\begin{document}
\today

7. desember 2016
\end{document}
```

[image]

This does not happen when compiling with `babel`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[main = norsk]{babel}

\begin{document}
\today

7. desember 2016
\end{document}
```

[image]

Why does this happen? Bug? How can I fix it?

Comment: Reported: https://github.com/reutenauer/polyglossia/issues/171

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a spurious space in `gloss-norsk.ldf`:

```
\def\datenorsk{%   
   \def\today{\number\day.~\ifcase\month\or
    januar\or februar\or mars\or april\or mai\or juni\or
    juli\or august\or september\or oktober\or november\or desember
    \fi\space\number\year}%
    }
```

There is no `%` after `desember`, which makes for an additional space when the current month is December.

Temporary fix: add

```
\def\datenorsk{%   
   \def\today{\number\day.~\ifcase\month\or
    januar\or februar\or mars\or april\or mai\or juni\or
    juli\or august\or september\or oktober\or november\or desember%
    \fi\space\number\year}%
    }
```

in the preamble.